# Building a view from a JSON stringified array of objects in the original table column

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Given an original table in Athena that is similar to this contrived example below:

**Original Table:**

| a | b | cmsmessage | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | {"asset": {"metadata": {"item": [{"key": "author", "value": "Rob"}, { "key": "id", "value": "123"}, {"key": "version", "value": "1"}]}}} | ... |
| ... | ... | {"asset": {"metadata": {"item": [{ "key": "id", "value": "456"}, {"key": "author", "value": "John"}, {"key": "version", "value": "3"}]}}} | ... |
| ... | ... | {"asset": {"metadata": {"item": [{"key": "version", "value": "2"}, {"key": "author", "value": "Sally"}, {"key": "id", "value": "789" }]}}} | ... |

I am trying to create a View from the stringified JSON in the `cmsmessage` column:

**Desired Resultant View:**

| id | author | version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Rob | 1 |
| 456 | John | 3 |
| 789 | Sally | 3 |

As you can see in the *"Desired Resultant View"* I'm essentially wanting to extract the data from each object of the `item` array based on the value of the `key` value.

`[{"key": "author", "value": "Rob"}, { "key": "id", "value": "123"}, {"key": "version", "value": "1"}]`

---

I've seen/tried various examples that access items in an array by index, e.g. `[0]` such as the [examples in Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html). However the index position in the array may vary given the json/string in the `cmsmessage` column of the original table.

---

**My Failed attempt:**

Below shows my failed attempt:

```sql
WITH dataset AS 
(
   SELECT *
   FROM (VALUES 
     ('{"asset": {"metadata": {"item": [{"key": "author", "value": "Rob"}, { "key": "id", "value": "123"}, {"key": "version", "value": "1"}]}}}'),
     ('{"asset": {"metadata": {"item": [{ "key": "id", "value": "456"}, {"key": "author", "value": "John"}, {"key": "version", "value": "3"}]}}}'),
     ('{"asset": {"metadata": {"item": [{"key": "version", "value": "2"}, {"key": "author", "value": "Sally"}, {"key": "id", "value": "789" }]}}}')
  ) AS t (cmsmessage)
)

SELECT
    json_extract_scalar(objArray, '$.key') as _keys,
    json_extract_scalar(objArray, '$.value') as _values
FROM dataset

CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_extract(cmsmessage, '$.asset.metadata.item') as array(json))) as t (objArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably the easiest option would be using [`json_query`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#filter) which has better support for JSON path syntax:

```sql
SELECT json_query(cmsmessage, 'lax $.asset.metadata.item[*]?(@.key=="id").value') AS id
    , json_query(cmsmessage, 'lax $.asset.metadata.item[*]?(@.key=="author").value') AS author
    , json_query(cmsmessage, 'lax $.asset.metadata.item[*]?(@.key=="version").value') AS version
FROM dataset;
```

Should work for Athena engine version 3 which is based on Trino.

For version 2 you can achieve similar with array manipulation.